# Cannot install/update Algolia Search

Tags: magento, magento2, algolia

I'm trying to install Algolia Search for my Magento 2 store using

composer require algolia/algoliasearch-magento-2

However, it won't go through http://prntscr.com/oxxv08
Could you please let me know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot you have invalid Magento keys. Why don't add the Algolia composer require into the composer configs first and run a composer install after?

Seems more of dependencies or validation issues.

Comment: I've added the credentials, however, the issue still persists: http://prntscr.com/oyxg0z

Comment: @LuanTran add the line to the composer.json of your project folder instead, "require": {
        "algolia/algoliasearch-magento-2": "^1.11" like that. And run composer install after. If that doesn't work, you have permission issues with composer on your bash